# Normally distributed with probability

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

Assume the length of waiting at supermarket is approximately normally distributed with mean 6 minutes and standard deviation 1.5 minutes.

(1) Fund the probability that waiting time is longer than 8 minutes
My way is $P(z > \frac{8-6}{1.5}) = P(z > \frac{4}{3}) = .0918$

(2) What length of the waiting time constitutes the 99th percentile ($Φ_.99$)?
My way is 
First find $p(z > 2.575) = .005 $ and $p(z < -2.575) = .005$
find $(y-6)/1.5 = 2.575 <=> y = 9.8625$ and$ (y-6)/1.5 = -2.575 <=> y = 2.1375$.
The waiting time length is between 2.14 and 9.86.

(3) Find probability that waiting time lasted longer than $6$ minutes given that it lasted longer than $5$ minutes
My way is $P(Y>6|Y>5)= \frac{P(Y>6,Y>5)}{P(Y>5)} = \frac{P(Y>6)}{P(Y>5)} = \frac{P(z > \frac{6-6}{1.5})}{P(z > \frac{5-6}{1.5})} = P(z > 0) /P(z > \frac{-2}{3}) = \frac{.5}{1-.2514}=.67$

Could anyone please check (1), (2), (3) for me?

Comment: In #2), the 99 percentile is 1-tailed, i.e., the duration from $0$ to the $99$th percentile.

Comment: For the 99 percentile, $p(z > 2.237) = .01 $ 
find $(y-6)/1.5 = 2.327 <=> y = 9.4905$ For the 0 percentile, y is going to be negative infinity...the waiting length is between 0, since negative number is not practically, and 9.4905....is (2) now right?

Comment: @user99680:please check

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3 look right (I didn't do out the calculations, just looked at your set-up). The previous answer addressed 2.

Comment: For the 99 percentile, $p(z > 2.237) = .01 $ 
find $(y-6)/1.5 = 2.327 <=> y = 9.4905$ For the 0 percentile, y is going to be negative infinity...the waiting length is between 0, since negative number is not practically, and 9.4905....is (2) now right?

Comment: please check!!!!